# SQL Server: Output parameter to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parameters, output

I have the next T-SQL code:

```
DECLARE @A CHAR(1)
DECLARE @B CHAR(10)
DECLARE @C DECIMAL
DECLARE @D CHAR(1)

SET @A = 'S'
SET @B = '2015-03-23'
SET @C = 1
SET @D = 'P'

EXEC('CALL DATA_COLLECTOR(?,?,?,?)',@A, @B, @C, @D) at LINKED_SERVER_10

PRINT @D
```

@D is an input-ouput variable.

After running the code, the variable @D gets a result set (5 rows, 10 columns).

How can I copy the result set contained in @D to another table in my database?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "the variable gets a table" mean?

Comment: The output parameter gets a result set of 5rows x 10columns.

Comment: Still don't know how you have defined an output parameter that accepts a char(1) as input but outputs a "result set"... can you show the stored procedure code so we don't have to try to guess what it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output cannot be `CHAR(1)`

If you ignore `@D` and just want to store the result set of your procedure into a table, then you have few choices to do:

1. Table has been created before

   ```
   CREATE TABLE #Table (Field1 INT, Field2 VARCHAR(50));
   INSERT INTO #Table
   EXEC yourProcedure
   ```

To see the result

```
    SELECT *
    FROM #Table
```

2. Create table at runtime using `OPENROWSET`

   ```
   sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
   GO
   RECONFIGURE
   GO
   sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
   GO
   RECONFIGURE

   SELECT * INTO #Table
   FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
   'EXEC tempdb.dbo.yourProcedure')
   ```

To see the result

```
    SELECT *
    FROM #Table
```

Comment: Yes, I was wrong!, the @D parameter just give me a char, Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new table from the variable, use

```
SELECT * INTO newTable FROM @D
```

To put the data into an existing table, use

```
INSERT INTO existingTable SELECT * FROM @D
```